# Problem with get data from QTextEdit and save it

Tags: python, excel, database, pyqt5, save

I create A program that have many variables like name ... i want to get name in QTextEdit as function and save it to excell but i cant ....

```
class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        self.name = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.name.toPlainText()
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 40, 171, 31))
        self.name.setStyleSheet("background:\n"
"    white;\n"
"border-radius:\n"
"   5px;\n"
"border-style:\n"
"    solid;\n"
"border-width:\n"
"    1px;")
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
   #save button
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 670, 93, 28))
        self.save.setStyleSheet("background:\n"
"    white;\n"
"border-radius:\n"
"   14px;\n"
"border-style:\n"
"    solid;\n"
"border-width:\n"
"   2px;\n"
"border-color: \n"
"    qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 blue, stop: 1 red)\n"
"    red\n"
"    qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 blue, stop: 1 red)\n"
"    blue;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.save.setObjectName("save")

     def get_data(self):
        name=self.name.toPlainText()
        # Get the data from the input fields
        name = self.name.toPlainText()
      
      
        # Create a dictionary from the data
        data = {"name":name}

        return data
    
    def save_data(self):
        self.save.clicked.connect(self.save_data())
        # Get the data and create a DataFrame
        data = self.get_data()
        df = pd.DataFrame([data])
        # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
        df.to_excel("D:/data.xlsx", index=False)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_mainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i expect TO write name in qtextedit and save it by save func...
how can save button get data from name qtextedit?

Comment: You could remove `self.save.clicked.connect(self.save_data())` from `save_data()` and add `self.save.clicked.connect(self.save_data)` (*whitout the final parentheses!*) into `setupUi()`. But that would be conceptually wrong anyway, since you're **NOT** expected to edit pyuic files, as the warned by the header you ignored and removed. Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) and also some tutorials about *properly* using signals (like [this one](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/)).

Comment: all of problems solved ! last qustion  `def get_data(self):
        name=self.name.toPlainText()` so this is true for get variable from qtextedit?

Comment: Just ask yourself the following questions: 1. does it work? 2. did you check the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html)? If `1` is true, then it's *probably* correct, and, in **either** case, point `2` is a mandatory step.